# ASP.Net - Collecting 0 or more groups of inputs (Like Address History)

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on creating a form that can collect someones address history but I don't know the best way to dynamically capture this considering a person may have a history of 0 or more places.

Here is the base template:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_Address" runat="server"></td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txt_Zip" runat="server"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Button ID=btn_AddAnother" runat="server" Text="Add Another Address OnClick="???"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are many of ways of doing this. Could you add the server side code where you save the data from the textboxes?

Comment: I haven't created that yet as I have no idea how to build out the part that creates the dynamic input groups.